# Photon Network Player.SetCustomProperties not working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, photon

I am currently building an online game with Photon Networking using Unity and I have a problem with [Photon.Realtime.Player.SetCustomProperties()](https://doc-api.photonengine.com/en/pun/v2/class_photon_1_1_realtime_1_1_player.html#a73265fc7665581640574dc7e98526c77) method. I've already googled it but I couldn't find anything like my issue.

### About the project

The matchmaking system is nothing very fancy: I have a first scene to login (without password for now), that will connect to Photon. When `OnConnectedToMaster` event is raised I load the lobby scene that will display the rooms. And finally, when `OnJoinedRoom` is called I load a 3rd scene for the room itself, it will display the players, set teams, game config, etc.

I've made an extension class both for [Player](https://doc-api.photonengine.com/en/pun/v2/class_photon_1_1_realtime_1_1_player.html) and [Room](https://doc-api.photonengine.com/en/pun/v2/class_photon_1_1_realtime_1_1_room_info.html) (RoomInfo) classes to make it easier and clean to get/set the Custom Properties.

### The issue

As soon as I load the Room scene I want to get a few properties from the Player to display in the Room, like MMR (ranking), for example. So I made the following code:

```
public static class PlayerExtensions
{
    private static readonly string _mmrProperty = "mmr";

    public static void SetMmr(this Player player, int mmr)
    {
        player.SetCustomProperties(new Hashtable() { { _mmrProperty, mmr.ToString() } });
    }

    public static int GetMmr(this Player player)
    {
        return (int)player.CustomProperties[_mmrProperty];
    }
}
```

After getting null exception error on `GetMmr()` I realized the player doesn't have the actual 'mmr' Custom Property in it. So I debugged the `SetMmr()` and I noticed a few things:

- the player already have some custom properties that I never set, called "name" and "hideFlags".
- `SetCustomProperties()` doesn't do anything at all. I was expecting it to create/change the 'mmr' property, but it doesn't
- If I directly change `player.CustomProperties` it works. However it doesn't seem to be the right approach.

This is me debugging it on 3 steps: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rMyzR.jpg

So, I am not sure what to do next since the `SetCustomProperties()` doesn't seem to work.
Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure you try to get that property from a player that has actually set it first?

Comment: @derHugo Of course. I updated the question with this link: https://imgur.com/a/YI24dP0 3 images showing the issue during debugging process

Answer (score 3, accepted):

tl;dr

- never set `Player.CustomProperties` or `Room.CustomProperties` directly (use them as read-only), instead always use `SetCustomProperties` methods.
- wait for `OnPlayerPropertiesUpdate` callback before trying to access updated property value you just set.

> By default, setting properties for actor or room properties will not
> take effect on the sender/setter client (actor that sets the
> properties) immediately when joined to an online room unlike what it
> used to be in PUN Classic. Now, instead, the sender/setter client
> (actor that sets the properties) will wait for the server event
> `PropertiesChanged` to apply/set changes locally. So you need to wait
> until `OnPlayerPropertiesUpdate` or `OnRoomPropertiesUpdate` callbacks
> are triggered for the local client in order to access them. The new
> behaviour is due to the introduction of the new room option flag
> `roomOptions.BroadcastPropsChangeToAll` which is set to `true` by
> default. The reason behind this is that properties can easily go out
> of synchronization if we set them locally first and then send the
> request to do so on the server and for other actors in the room. The
> latter might fail and we may end up with properties of the
> sender/setter client (actor that sets the properties) different
> locally from what's on the server or on other clients. If you want to
> have the old behaviour (set properties locally before sending the
> request to the server to synchronize them) set
> `roomOptions.BroadcastPropsChangeToAll` to `false` before creating
> rooms. But we highly recommend against doing this.

[source](https://doc.photonengine.com/en-us/pun/current/getting-started/migration-notes#callbacks_changes)

Comment: Thats it!! I was not aware of those callback methods but they make a lot of sense. Thank you John